# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod - Handling special characters in Uri

Tags: powershell, urlencode, invoke-restmethod

In powershell I am calling a rest API using Invoke-RestMethod. I am passing query string arguments whose values can have special characters and they are causing errors.

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://<something>.com?Key=<value>
```

Everything works fine as long as `<value>` is a normal string or numbers.

But if `<value>` contains any special characters like "a:1" or "a\u0000", it errors out stating

**`{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}`**

I tried urlencoding the Uri but it doesn't work.

```
$encodedvalue = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode(<value>)
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://<something>.com?key=$encodedvalue
```

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you try `[uri]::EscapeDataString(<value>)` ? P.S. You're missing a closing double-quote on the Invoke-RestMethod in both examples.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below code snippet. This one handles the null character
`[uri]::EscapeUriString([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode([char]0x0000)`